# Sequential Date in Header for Excel when printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

Is there a macro that can be done so that when I print certain excel forms that need to be for certain dates (I.E. August 28, 2017 - September 1, 2017) where it will print the next date on each page? 
So it prints the same form 5 times and the first page has August 28,2017 and the last page would have September 1,2017 printed in the header? Center preferred.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure someone will point out, SE is not a code writing service. Since you don't indicate otherwise, I'll assume you have some familiarity with Excel VBA.
One way to accomplish this is to write a macro that changes your header and inside that macro include the print function. There are probably other methods, but one I used to print random Bingo cards was:

> ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

Inside that macro you can include input boxes to print the number of copies you need.
**Edit:** I wrote some code many years ago, which I still have, that prints a unique Bingo card on each printout. If you're interested, I can post that code, and you can make the necessary changes to suit your needs.

Comment: nice joke trickster. -.-

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to as "joke." I've given you what I believe is a good starting point. But if you find this answer unhelpful, I will be pleased to delete it.